# can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am using a **cellranger mkref** and faced with a strange python problem with GTF (custom gtf file):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/lib/python/cellranger/reference.py", line 750, in validate_gtf
    subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/external/anaconda/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/external/anaconda/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['gtf_to_gene_index', '/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/indexes', '/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/indexes/tmp74f_vsxg.json']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/bin/rna/mkref", line 139, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/bin/rna/mkref", line 130, in main
    reference_builder.build_gex_reference()
  File "/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/lib/python/cellranger/reference.py", line 613, in build_gex_reference
    self.validate_gtf()
  File "/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/lib/python/cellranger/reference.py", line 753, in validate_gtf
    raise GexReferenceError("Error detected in GTF file: " + exc.output) from exc
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Also, I have a similar gtf file, which cellranger accepts without problems. I compared those files (moreover, the first one I made from the second one):

file 1: `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`
file 2: `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

Also, I checked with `cat -vE` and the files is the same and tried to convert to utf-8 or find some words like b'word', but nothing

How can I change the file?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 3 treats strings of *bytes* as a different object from strings of *characters*. The distinction matters, since a given string of characters can be encoded to bytes in different ways. E.g. in UTF-8, `ä` is the two bytes `c3 a4` (in hex), while in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1encoding) (Latin 1), it's just the single byte `e4`.

Like the comment from @Theophrastus says, [`subprocess.check_output()` returns bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), matching the low-level API. You need to decode it to characters based on what the expected encoding is. E.g.

```
>>> raw = subprocess.check_output("ls")
>>> raw
b'\xc3\xa4iti\n'
>>> out = raw.decode('utf-8')
>>> out
'äiti\n'
```

Note the byte string is marked as `b''` while the character string is just `''` with no letter.

In recent versions, it seems you should also be able to pass `encoding="utf-8"` to `check_output()` directly.

If the data contains just ASCII characters, you could of course use `.decode('ascii')` instead. It will throw an exception if the input contains bytes with the high bit set.